# A novel featuring an Earth without a moon

Tags: story-identification, novel

About a decade ago, I read a novel about an Earth without a moon. It talked of a dimensional portal, where you could experience a series of situations (with and without moon) and how things changed with new conditions. It featured Neanderthals in the present day, although apprehensive of new technologies. There were modern matriarchal scientists who had gorilla like bodies to withstand the wind created by the rotation of the Earth without a moon, and who also acquired very long names. There were religious zealots (priests) with monkey tails.

Comment: Do you remember anything more about these situations? Was it just with/without a moon or were there any other situations (such as closer moon, bigger sun etc)?

Comment: This sounds very interesting, I'd like to read this. I do know that Isaac Asimov wrote two essays on the topic of "what if Earth did not have a moon?" - one talking about the benefits to the human race, one talking about the negative aspects, so that might also be something to read for anyone interested in this.

Comment: @Ayshe Hey, I just noticed you've been making a lot of edits in quick succession. While improvements to posts are always welcome, we do ask that people not do too many at one go, because all the edited posts get bumped to the front page of the site. A rough rule of thumb is that at most 5 of the top 15 posts on the active questions lists should have been last edited by the same person. Could you please give it a rest and come back to editing later?

Comment: @Randal'Thor, sure, stopping now. I didn't know about the rule of thumb.I thought it wouldn't matter since they were on the front page (or on the [story-identification] tagged one?) already.

Comment: My question has been answered. It is "Origin" from Stephen Baxter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like Stephen Baxter's "[Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(Baxter_novel)/)", the third book in the Manifold
Trilogy

- There are multiple alternate Earths, at least one without a moon
- There were some Homo Erectus and something like Neanderthals
- Hyper intelligent, matriarchal scientists from an Earth with very strong winds due to an extreme axial tilt

Comment: It is indeed!!! Thank you very much!!